# Where is Java installed in OSX Mavericks?

Tags: macos, java

I am setting up Maven on my Mac but it is not working because the JAVA_HOME variable is not defined. I had expected the java installer to create this but alas not.

Where is java installed so I can create this variable myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

George Garside's path is correct. Latest JDK released today from Oracle. I advise downloading directly from [Oracle's Site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html). Use the symlink to create your `JAVA_HOME` variable. 
Add the following to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` profile.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Just downloaded the kit and added the above to my `.bash_profile`.
As you can see, variable is now clearly defined:

```
Macbook-Pro:~ njboot$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Returns:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<version>.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: It's not your time, is it?